# RPC to get Windows event logs using Python

Tags: python, linux, windows, rpc, event-log

I'm an absolute newbie so it might explain why I'm having trouble, but I haven't been able to find any information on using Python to make RPC calls to Microsoft Windows systems so that I can get back event log information.

I'm on the verge of giving up. Maybe it's because I don't understand much of RPC. I thought googling would help me get the required information, but it's been a week and I've made absolutely no progress. Could someone here please point me in the right direction? It would help a lot.

Comment: I think your question needs to be a little more specific. A simple google search of "python rpc" gives me half a dozen RPC libraries and solutions for Python.

Comment: I'm going to have to try and use the PyMSRPC library. Hopefully it will be what I'm looking for.